# pandas dataframe data retrieval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my sample pandas data frame

```
              icd_code   from_date  paid_amount
claim_id                                       
CKEY-7724339    719.43  2015-09-26       300.09
CKEY-5008998     722.2  2015-04-21        11.65
CKEY-7896598       722  2015-02-23        17.19
CKEY-7758556     850.9  2014-03-13       414.02
CKEY-7749118     847.0  2012-07-18         4.42
CKEY-10383160   854.00  2015-06-16       751.68
CKEY-10678452   607.84  2015-07-07        11.13
CKEY-10734364    882.2  2015-07-22      5625.00
CKEY-3500566    307.89  2011-08-09       500.00
CKEY-10766667    344.1  2013-12-03       139.41
```

When I use .loc to retrieve, the output is as follows

```
$ indexed_data.loc['CKEY-10766667']
icd_code            344.1
from_date      2013-12-03
paid_amount        139.41
Name: CKEY-10766667, dtype: object

~~~~~~~~expected output ~~~~~~~~~~
CKEY-10766667    344.1  2013-12-03       139.41
```

Can someone point me what's wrong in the above code

Note : I have call data.set_index('claim_id') on original data set to created index on 'claim_id'.

Comment: why do you expect that output? what is returned is a `Series` representing that row

Comment: When I have more than one rows with same index, the output is as expected output

Comment: What is the type of your expected output? `.loc` returns a `pandas.Series`, if you only want the values, you can use `indexed_data.loc['CKEY-10766667'].values`

Comment: No, when you have multiple rows you get a df returned and it will show the index as a column

Comment: @EdChum I want to return df even when I have a single row. Can you help me with it

Comment: Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: You can do `indexed_data.loc['CKEY-10766667'].to_frame().T` but this is only valid where it will return a single row

Comment: My dataframe will have dupicate indexes and some uniqu indexes. I'm going to retrieve 'df' based on index value and apply .isin() method for some data transormation. When I have multiple rows .isin() works fine but when I have single row, I get expection 'KeyError: 'icd_code''

Comment: Using indexed_data.loc[['CKEY-8369057']] give me output I expect. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code below gave me the expected ouput:

```
$>>> indexed_data.loc[['CKEY-8369057']]
```

Passing single value to .loc will return a Dataframe when multiple rows exist and a Series if only one row exists. But passing a list to .loc will always return a Dataframe.

Consider execution time into account, passing a list consumes more time than a single element, especially when the statement is inside a loop. Here is what I did to achieve better execution time

```
df = indexed_data.loc[x]
if type(df).__name__ == 'Series':
    df = df.to_frame().T
```

The above code makes sure that the we have a dataframe at the end of these three lines.